# Expo Document Picker is not sending file with Http API Request

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I am trying to send the selected document in the API request, but the API is not getting the file, the same API is working fine with postman and web.

```
const pickDocument = async () => {
    const { uri, name, file } = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
      type: "*/*",
      copyToCacheDirectory: true,
    });

    try {

      const blob = await getBlob(uri, name);
      const file = await blobToFile(blob, name);
      setBlobFile(file);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERR: " + error.message);
    }
  };
```

```
export const blobToFile = (theBlob, fileName) => {
  //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
  theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  theBlob.name = fileName;
  return file;
};

export const getBlob = async (fileUri, name) => {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(fileUri);
    const imageBody = await resp.blob();
    console.log("imageBody:", imageBody);
    return imageBody;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("blob err:::", err);
    //toast err
  }
};
```

`<Button title="Select Document" onPress={pickDocument} />`